# Relative paths not valid for embedding fonts with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to embed a font, the way I always do with the CSS generated by FontSquirrel, only with a relative path:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('config/templates/fonts/MyFont.eot');
    src: url('config/templates/fonts/MyFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('config/templates/fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('config/templates/fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('config/templates/fonts/MyFont.svg#MyFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**This does not seem to work.**

Changing it to `/base/config/templates/fonts...` fixes the problem, but for the sake of the application, it would be preferable to use relative paths.

The font files **do** exist relative to the document that is using them.

Are relative paths for font importing just not acceptable?  What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
./config/templates/fonts/...
```

Or in some cases:

```
../config/templates/fonts/...
```

Depending on your structure.

Comment: How about:
/../config/templates/fonts/